# Using Page anchors on django

Tags: google-app-engine, django-templates

I would like to have AppEngine render an html page that auto scrolls to an html anchor point.  I'm not sure how and where to put that type of instruction.

```
    template_values = { 
    'foo' : 'foo',
    'bar': 'bar',
    'anchor' : '#MyPageAnchor'  # ?? Something like this...
    }
    path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), fileName) 
    self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
```

Is this possible?  How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing App Engine specific here. You simply have to redirect the user to a URL that includes the anchor (eg, http://example.com/foo#anchor).